# How to recognize if a model is overfitting?

Tags: neural-network, overfitting

I'm trying to develop a real-time YOLOv8 model for detecting falls in a home environment.
The dataset I used consists of approximately 1100 images labeled as "fall" and "nofall," with about 500 images used for the validation phase. Of course, these validation images are not part of the training dataset, but they still represent falls in a home environment.

The model was trained with fine-tuning for 100 epochs, and additionally, the "patience=50" parameter was set to prevent overfitting.
After training, I obtain the following results, which I am attaching below and I believe to be good. In addition, testing the model in real-time appears to work reasonably well.
Most importantly, I would like to understand if the model is indeed not overfitting.
[image]
Thanks to anyone who can help!

Comment: To see if a model is overfitting you generally compare the performing on the training dataset with the test/validation dataset. In your case I would say the model is overfitting since the loss on the validation dataset is higher than on the training dataset after a few epochs. Additionally, the different validation losses are increasing as  training continues.

Comment: Can't say it better than @Oxbowerce. Notice that the absolute validation losses are much higher than training losses.

Comment: @Oxbowerce And then why, when testing it in real-time (in my home environment, which is different from the images it was trained on), does the model perform decently? Regarding overfitting, I used early stopping to try to prevent it, but from the photo I showed, it doesn't seem to have worked very well (the model was supposed to train for 100 epochs, but I noticed it stopped at epoch 57 due to early stopping).

Comment: @Oxbowerce I believe the issue stems from the variability of the dataset, in the sense that it consists of approximately 1000 images that are all very similar. These images are extracted from videos shot in different areas of the house, and the frames extracted are consequently quite similar to each other. For validation, the reasoning is the same (images from videos but obviously different from those in training). I was thinking of trying to implement cross-validation, but if the dataset is not representative, I'm unsure how much sense it would make. Any advice?

Comment: The model overfitting does not necessarily mean that the performance will be bad, it is expected that the model will have similar performance out of sample as on the test set (which might be decent or still very well). Given the small dataset, you might want to try augmentation methods to artifically increase the number of data points can learn from (if you even want to continue training given you mention the decent model performance). Additionally, you could stop training roughly 10 epochs since the validation performance decreases after that point.

Comment: @Oxbowerce I had already tried to perform data augmentation, but the results seemed much worse than those I had obtained previously (I have modified the photo attached to the post to show them to you). The training is always done in the same way, for 100 epochs and with early stopping, but this time the train runned for all 100 epoch. Should I train it for many more epochs, or will the already observed overfitting not decrease even if I, for example, do 200 epochs?